# lprng (red hat enterprise 5.4) installation sh syntax error from make

Tags: linux, installation, makefile, redhat

LPRNG installation
I follow the standard procedures, typing
sh STANDARD-CONFIGURATION
make clean 
make all

I downloaded LPRng-3.8.35.tar

I am running Red Hat Linux Release 5.4 Enterprise (Tikanga)

The latter generates a simple sh syntax.  It surprises me
that the make would not run correctly on what is an “out-of-box”
install.

Here is the script from the attempt to do the make.

```
 make all
if [ "UTILS" != po -o "yes" != "no" ] ; then \
        cd UTILS; make localedir=/usr/share/locale \
            DESTDIR= all ; \
    fi
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/bin/sh: line 1:    cd UTILS; make localedir=/usr/share/locale \: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 2:        DESTDIR= all ; \: command not found
/bin/sh: -c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/bin/sh: -c: line 3: `fi'
make: *** [UTILS] Error 2
```

Comment: LPRng http://www.lprng.com/LPRng-HOWTO-Multipart/x962.html  ,,, http://www.lprng.com/LPRng-HOWTO-Multipart/installation.html#AEN350  ... LPRng-3.8.35 is an old version (2010). Latest is " lprng-3.8.C.tar.gz", 2012  http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/lprng/lprng/lprng-3.8.C.tar.gz

Comment: Mr. Larsen's suggestion of switching to 3.8.C solved the problem and it completed the installation fine.